# Referenced Assembly is Not Recognised

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010

In my C# project I have added a managed reference to "Microsoft.ExtendedReflection".

I can see this assembly and browse it's classes in the Visual Studio's "Object Browser" but when I try to use it in my code

```
using Microsoft.ExtendedReflection.Utilities;
```

I get the following error:

> Error 22 The type or namespace name 'ExtendedReflection' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

It is quite strange and happens only with this assembly (it is part of Pex, other assemblies I have referenced did not have such problem). What can be the reason for this?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your screenshot shows the reference being added to the `PexMe` project, but the errors occurring in the `PexMeHelper` project. Did you just forget to add a reference within that project too?

Answer (score 1):

I would say that the dependency assembly requires the full version of the framework and your project requires the Client profile only. Try to switch your project to Full.

Comment: I'm so glad you reminded me of this "feature" of the client profile